# Boost not found error while doing make for CRAVE software

Tags: boost, cmake

In CMakelist.txt shows ,

```
PROJECT(metaSMT)
      2 
      3 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)
      4 include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
      5 if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.3)
      6   include(cmake/feature_summary_stub.cmake)
      7 else()
      8   include(FeatureSummary)
      9 endif()
     10 
     11 include(CTest)
     12 
     13 set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules )
     14 
     15 set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE true)
     16 set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS true)
     17 set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.50.0")
     18 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS iostreams thread python)
     19 
     20 if(NOT ${Boost_FOUND})
     21   message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost could not be found.")
     22 endif()
     23
```

So it do make, I got a error,

```
./bootstrap.sh -d /home/tandv0011/crave-bundle/deps -m RELEASE /home/tan        dv0011/crave-bundle/build
      2 skipping boost-1_50_0
      3 skipping SWORD-1.1
      4 skipping cudd-2.4.2
      5 -- Could NOT find Boost
      6 CMake Error at metaSMT/CMakeLists.txt:21 (message):
      7   Boost could not be found.
```

Can you please Guide me to fix this issue

Comment: And what have you tried (like setting variables)? Why do you set Boost_* variables?

Comment: Add -DBOOST_ROOT=[path where your boost can be found] to cmake command line